Unable to Install Python 2 on Parrot OS
I'm facing an issue while trying to install Python 2 on my Parrot OS. Whenever I run the command:
sudo apt-get install python2
I receive the following output:
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
dh-python
E: Package 'python2' has no installation candidate`
I also tried using sudo apt install python2, and even updated the repository file /etc/apt/sources.list, but I'm still unable to install Python 2.
Does anyone have a solution for this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
In attempting to install Python 2 on my Parrot OS, I first used the command sudo apt-get install python2, which resulted in an error stating that the package python2 was not available. I then attempted to use sudo apt install python2, but encountered the same issue.
My expectation was that either of these commands would successfully install Python 2 on my system, allowing me to use it for development purposes or to satisfy dependencies for other software. However, despite updating the repository file /etc/apt/sources.list to include relevant sources, I was unable to proceed with the installation.

Python 2 is obsolete. That said, installation of packages is system administration, so it's off-topic here.

It might be python2.7
sudo apt-get install python2.7

Instead of python2
sudo apt-get install python2

https://packages.debian.org/buster/python2.7

Tried that as well: sudo apt-get install python2.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python2.7
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python2.7'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python2.7'
